# Why does "name it to tame it" work from an evolutionary psychology perspective?

Tags: neuroscience, emotion, evolutionary-psychology

There seems to exist a phenomenon where being aware of one's feelings gives us power over them. I have seen this in everyday life, but the strongest piece of evidence I've seen is from a [talk by UCLA Psychology professor Dan Siegel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZcDLzppD4Jc) who talks about his research putting people in brain scanners and getting them to name their emotions, and he says:

> If you can get her left brain to name the emotion, her left brain will
>   squirt soothing neurotransmitters into her lower brain

My question is: why do we have this mechanism? Do we have any idea how it evolved and what sort of evolutionary pressures or environments led to it? (Should I be asking Siegel himself? :P)

Comment: Related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/19298/word-for-naming-your-negative-self-talk-to-overcome-it